# How to use substring in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have this value

> ABSCDD::12345::YTGYGG

sometimes it may be

> ABSCDD::12345

I just want to get the value as

> **12345**

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the  [substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [charindex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) documentation

Answer (score 0):

The comment is right, but this should work: `SUBSTRING ( x ,8 , 5 )`. x is here one of your two strings.

<s>EDIT: This is better if the length before `::` is variable: `SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x,'::',1), 1, 5)`.</s>

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX` doesn't exist in SQL Server

Comment: So let's forget about it ;-) Thanks for correction!